# Value of threadidx.x (.y, .z), blockidx.x etc. in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I understand that I use threadidx.x etc. to reference a specific thread, but I am transferring code from a for loop in a CPU and would like to reference numbers 0...N using threadidx.x, but this doesn't seem to work.  I declare tdx = threadIdx.x as an integer, but what integer is actually being stored in tdx?

Answer (score 13):

As you can [read in the documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#thread-hierarchy), the variables `threadIdx`,  `blockIdx` and `blockDim` are variables that are created automatically on every execution thread. They have `.x`, `.y` and `.z` properties so that you can map threads to your problem space as you see fit.

When you execute the kernel, you determine how many threads each block will have (in 3D) and how many blocks there are in a 3D grid. In the following code:

```
dim3 threads(tX, tY, tZ);
dim3 blocks(gX, gY, gZ);

kernel_function<<<blocks, threads>>>(kernel_parameters);
```

You are launching the kernel function named `kernel_function` so that the CUDA runtime launches a 3D grid of blocks of dimensions `gX`x`gY`x`gZ`. Each of those blocks will *contain* threads organized in a 3D structure of size `tX`x`tY`x`tZ`.

If the size of the 3rd dimension is 0 (i.e. it is a 2D mapping), the picture of the official documentation shows it better:

[image: Official CUDA thread hierarchy]

What this means is that the following will be true for every thread executing your kernel:

- `blockDim.x = tX`
- `blockDim.y = tY`
- `blockDim.z = tZ`
- `gridDim.x = gX`
- `gridDim.y = gY`
- `gridDim.z = gZ`

And every thread will have its own coordinates within those parameters. Mathematically:

- `0 <= threadIdx.x < blockDim.x = tX`
- `0 <= threadIdx.y < blockDim.y = tY`
- `0 <= threadIdx.z < blockDim.z = tZ`
- `0 <= blockIdx.x < gridDim.x = gX`
- `0 <= blockIdx.y < gridDim.y = gY`
- `0 <= blockIdx.z < gridDim.z = gZ`

Comment: PS: this is a really basic CUDA question, I really recommend you to read the official CUDA Programming Guide

Comment: what is `threadDim` ??  You've got some of your built-in variables confused.  The grid dimensions are `gridDim.x,y,z` in units of blocks.  The block dimensions are `blockDim.x,y,z` in units of threads.  Each block has a unique index `blockIdx.x,y,z` within the grid. The only thread built-in variable is `threadIdx.x,y,z`, which is the thread index, unique within the block.

Comment: You are correct with regards to the variable names and I have corrected them (note to self: should not respond to SO questions after midnight)